# How i can Import a HTML-File from my GoogleDrive

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

is it possible to import a HTML-File i Google-Spreadsheet when the HTML-File is on my GoogleDrive or direct on my Computerdesktop? Currently i copy the HTML-File to my Homepage-Filestructure an then a connect them from the Spreadsheet.

It is very laborious - but it works. Is it possible to make the function "File / Import" per script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is a documentation that will guide you on how to [open files and convert google docs in your app](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app).

> An app registered with the **Import** option enabled in the **Drive UI
>   Integration** tab within the Drive API in the API Console can import
>   supported Google Doc formats. This means that if a user selects **Open
>   with** for a Google doc, the app can convert it to a format that the
>   app can handle. When **Open with** triggers a conversion this way,
>   Drive evaluates the MIME types an app can open (set during
>   [registration](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#setting_mime_types_and_extensions)) and extrapolates the list of formats that the app
>   can import.

Comment: Hello, i am complete overwhelmed. Do you have a simply example-script for me?

Comment: There is a sample script in the example.

Comment: Hello, it is to strange for me. You mean this [Page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app